# want to write node.js http client for web site testing

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js
I want to try to write node.js client for my web site testing
(stuff like login, filling forms, etc...)
Which module should i use for that?
Since I want to test user login following other user functionality
it should be able to keep session like browser
Also any site where it has example of using that module?
Thanks

Comment: you want to write a testing client from scratch or are you looking for the state of the art modules for behavior testing? It it's the latter, look at [casper](http://casperjs.org/) + [phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) and [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/).

Answer (score 1):

As Amenadiel has said in the comments, you might want to use something like Phantom.js for testing websites.

But if you're new to node.js maybe try with something light, like [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/).

An example from their home page:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");
// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://localhost:3000/", function () {
  // Fill email, password and submit form
  browser.
    fill("email", "zombie@underworld.dead").
    fill("password", "eat-the-living").
    pressButton("Sign Me Up!", function() {

      // Form submitted, new page loaded.
      assert.ok(browser.success);
      assert.equal(browser.text("title"), "Welcome To Brains Depot");

    })

});
```

Later on, when you get the hang of it, maybe switch to Phantom (which has webkit beneath, so it's not emulating the Dom).